# Regex to get value that comes after certain word

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, boost-regex

I have a string that will always be dynamic, each time it returns one of the values below:

Return 1 -> `Após o vencimento cobrar juros mora/dia de: R$ 3.44 ao dia Multa de: R$ 17,21 Valores expressos em Real (R$\f REMESSA CIP 263`

Return 2 -> `Após o vencimento cobrar juros mora/dia de: R$ 23.56 ao dia Multa de: R$ 117,80 Valores expressos em Real (R$\f REMESSA **PARCELA 01 / 02**`

I need to get the value that comes after '**(R$\f**', that is, I need a regular expression that returns me:

**REMESSA CIP 263` and REMESSA **PARCELA 01 / 02**

My regular expression is this -> **`/\(R\$\\f (.*?)/i`** but it is not working properly.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Double escape `$`  & `\f` and make the rest of line greedy like:

```
$arr = Array('Após o vencimento cobrar juros mora/dia de: R$ 3.44 ao dia Multa de: R$ 17,21 Valores expressos em Real (R$\f REMESSA CIP 263',
'Após o vencimento cobrar juros mora/dia de: R$ 23.56 ao dia Multa de: R$ 117,80 Valores expressos em Real (R$\f REMESSA **PARCELA 01 / 02** ');
foreach($arr as $str) {
    preg_match("/\(R\\$\\\\f (.*)/i", $str, $m);
    print_r($m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => (R$\f REMESSA CIP 263
    [1] =>  REMESSA CIP 263
)
Array
(
    [0] => (R$\f REMESSA **PARCELA 01 / 02** 
    [1] =>  REMESSA **PARCELA 01 / 02** 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a lookbehind assertion to prevent capturing `(R$\f`.
2. Make `.*?` greedy so it will actually match something.

result:

```
(?<=\(R\$\\f ).*
```